# What is the easiest method to upgrade existing project in laravel 5 to 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Is there any available tool to upgrade **laravel** to **version 5.5**?
I have to upgrade a large scale laravel 5.0  application to the latest version so that I can run the app in PHP 7. Any proper and easy method available?

Comment: The best method is go to google, write "upgrade laravel 5 to 5.5" and click "I'm feeling lucky". Then follow instructions from the creators of laravel itself.

Comment: @Amarnasan this made me laugh out loud in the office.

You aren't wrong, maybe try a similar approach but do something like:

"upgrade laravel 5 to 5.1" > "I'm feeling lucky" and then "upgrade laravel 5.1 to 5.2" > "I'm feeling lucky"; OP. Good luck

Comment: 5.1 supports PHP7.  Might want to start there.

Answer (score 1):

By following all [upgrade guides](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade).

Or if you want it done fast, by using a service like [Laravel Shift](https://laravelshift.com/). I have never used this service, so I cannot say how well this will work with bigger projects.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5.3 and below has a little different folder architecture, so you should care in such things as well. I usually do the following steps to upgrade from any version(**Mainly 5.4 and above**) to latest.

Step 1: Save a backup of composer.json and delete composer.json file from your project and copy new one from laravel master branch for upgrading to latest version. Run this command to upgrade framework dependency.

`composer update`

step 2: Now finds the application dependency(packages that you installed during application development) and installed it.

step 3. Address the breaking changes with debugging approach.

References: [Laravel Upgrade: Easiest way to upgrade laravel application from any version to latest version](http://esikai.com/laravel-upgrade-the-easiest-way-to-upgrade-your-laravel-application-from-any-version5x-6x-to-7x-in-no-time-79b4cfd94bce)